# Can we use aggregate function within aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select max(salary)
from employ
where salary < ( select max(salary)
                 from employ
                 having count(max(salary)>salary)=3);
```

Here I am trying to find out 4th max salary using aggregate function in aggregate function.It is showing an error Invalid use of group function.

What is wrong in it?please help

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to just use `limit`:

```
select max(salary) as salary
from employ
order by salary desc
limit 3, 1;
```

Comment: I have forgotten about offset option))

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. Instead you can `order by` `salary` in the descending order, then `limit` your result to 4 records and retrieve the minimum one:

```
select min(salary)
from ( select max(salary) as salary
       from employ
       order by salary desc
       limit 4)
```

Comment: why can't we use aggregate function within aggregate function?

Comment: @VarunTeja: Well, logically, because they are calculated on the different sets of data.

Comment: what are the different sets of data here for count and max?

Comment: @VarunTeja  
Well, in your case it doesn't even make sense – since in your query aggregation is performed on the whole set, without group by, so only one row is always returned, so possible count, if it was implemented correctly, would always return 1. By the different data set I meant that sometimes, for example, you have to find department with maximum total salary of all employees, so at first you should have found total sum per each department (dataset1) and only after that find maximum(dataset2).